# testssl.sh Fatal error No IPv4/IPv6 address(es) available

Tags: openssl, cygwin, tls1.2, testssl.sh

I'm trying to test SSL/TLS implemented in my server. I'm using [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/) for this. Since I'm using Windows 10, I'm running it over [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

However, when I try it like so:
`./testssl.sh https://www.google.com`
I get the following error
`Fatal error: No IPv4/IPv6 address(es) for "www.google.com" available`

[image]

Same happened with the internal server that I was trying to test. I remember I had tested in few months back and it had worked but Im surprised why its not working now.

Comment: it works in my cygwin 64bit on W10 Home

Comment: Put results as text in your question, not an inline image.

Comment: Do you have DNS resolution working on this box? Can a browser access `https://www.google.com/`? What does `nslookup www.google.com` says?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I had already put the result as text however, since it would be more relatable if seen as "seen on screen", I have also put the screenshot along with it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek my browser is able to access http://www.google.com and the result of `nslookup` is :
 nslookup www.google.com
 Server:  myrouter
 Address:  111.111.0.1

 Non-authoritative answer:
 Name:    www.google.com
 Addresses:  2404:6800:4007:80b::2004
           172.217.163.36

Comment: With this problem, I would first isolate the command inside the script, which is actually producing this error message. With this information, I would then ask this question at [sf].

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I ran into this problem on my Git Bash on an Windows 10 box today.

```
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045 ... x86_64 Msys
```

Since it is not answered and seems not resolved (https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/issues/1099), I just want to share how I get it to work:

I simply declared target host name in my HOSTS file.

In this case, testssl.sh (3.0.8 & 3.2) display:

```
 A record via:           /etc/hosts
```